# jszip only zipping one of the two files from url

Tags: javascript, jszip

I am trying to zip two files from an URL using the jszip add on and I am having a little issue.  I am trying to zip two files from a url(testing with imgur links currently), however only one of my files is being zipped. I am not sure if it is something I am doing wrong in my foreach function?

Any suggestions would be awesome thank you.

```
function urlToPromise(url) 
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) 
    {
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) 
        {
            if(err) 
            {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

(function () 
{
  var zip = new JSZip();
  var count = 0;
  var zipFilename = "instasamplePack.zip";
  var urls = [
    'https://i.imgur.com/blmxryl.png',
    'https://i.imgur.com/Ww8tzqd.png'
  ];

  function bindEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {
    if (el.addEventListener){
      // standard way
      el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent){
      // old IE
      el.attachEvent('on'+eventName, eventHandler);
    }
  }

  // Blob
  var blobLink = document.getElementById('kick');
  if (JSZip.support.blob) {
    function downloadWithBlob() {

      urls.forEach(function(url){
        var filename = "element" + count + ".png";
        // loading a file and add it in a zip file
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
          if(err) {
            throw err; // or handle the error
          }
          zip.file(filename, urlToPromise(urls[count]), {binary:true});
          count++;
          if (count == urls.length) {
            zip.generateAsync({type:'blob'}).then(function(content) {
              saveAs(content, zipFilename);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
    bindEvent(blobLink, 'click', downloadWithBlob);
  } else {
    blobLink.innerHTML += " (not supported on this browser)";
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
urls.forEach(function(url){
  var filename = "element" + count + ".png";               // 1
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
    count++;                                               // 2
  });
});
```

you execute `1` two times and when a download finish you call `2`. `count` is still zero in both cases (at `1`), you overwrite one image with the other (same name).

You also download each image two times: `urlToPromise` already calls `JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent`.

To fix that:

- use the [index parameter of the forEach callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters) instead of `count`
- JSZip accepts promises (and internally wait for them), `urlToPromise` already convert everything: use it
- don't try to wait for promises, JSZip already does that

This gives a new `downloadWithBlob` function:

```
function downloadWithBlob() {
  urls.forEach(function(url, index){
    var filename = "element" + index + ".png";
    zip.file(filename, urlToPromise(url), {binary:true});
  });
  zip.generateAsync({type:'blob'}).then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, zipFilename);
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you, your rewritten downloadWithBlob was what I needed